# Removing an element from Seq

Tags: scala

In this code, given a structure `Seq[Seq[String]]` I'm trying to get rid of  element "B" in each sequence. To do that, my intent is to replace the field with `None` and then flatten the Seq. Problem is that the flatten statement does not compile, why is that and how to fix this?

```
 object HelloScala extends App{

      Seq(Seq("A","B","C"),Seq("A","B","C")).map{ rec =>
          val rec2 = rec.zipWithIndex.map{ case (field, i) =>
                    if (field == "B")
                        None
                    else
                        field + i
          }
          println(rec2.flatten)
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The result of an assignment is `Unit`. Not what you want in a `map()`.
2. The compliment of `None` is `Some()`, which you'll want to use to keep the result type consistent.
3. `map()` followed by `flatten` can be combined in a `flatMap()`.

-

```
Seq(Seq("A","B","C"),Seq("A","B","C")).map { rec =>
  rec.zipWithIndex.flatMap { case (field, i) =>
    if (field == "B")
      None
    else
      Some(field + i)
  }
}
//res0: Seq[Seq[String]] = List(List(A0, C2), List(A0, C2))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are trying to do something that simple in such
a convoluted way. Here is the code inferred from your description:

```
val withoutB = Seq(Seq("A","B","C"),Seq("A","B","C")).map{ _.filterNot(_ == "B")}
val flattened = withoutB.flatten

println(withoutB)
println(flattened)
```

prints:

```
List(List(A, C), List(A, C))
List(A, C, A, C)
```

---

In the hope that it helps to understand your mistake, I've forced your code snippet to
compile, annotated it with additional types of all intermediate results, and printed them out:

```
val withNones: Seq[Seq[Any]] = Seq(Seq("A","B","C"),Seq("A","B","C")).map{ rec =>
  val rec2: Seq[Any] = rec.zipWithIndex.map{ case (field, i) =>
    if (field == "B")
        None
    else
        field + i
  }
  rec2
}

val flattenedWithNones: Seq[Any] = withNones.flatten

println(withNones)
println(flattenedWithNones)
```

it prints:

```
List(List(A0, None, C2), List(A0, None, C2))
List(A0, None, C2, A0, None, C2)
```

but this is most likely not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
scala> Seq(Seq("A","B","C"),Seq("A","B","C")).flatten.filterNot(_ == "B")
res0: Seq[String] = List(A, C, A, C)
```